# Bulk Row Insert In SQL For My Own Defined Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a suggestion for Bulk Row Insert In SQL For My Own Defined Columns,

My Table Name : `A`

Columns in My Table : `Column1`

```
Select * From A
```

Result :

```
A
--
```

Now I want to insert my following own rows in A table,

Ex :

```
A
--
Kapil

Dks

Sujeeth

Sks

Devid
```

My Query :

```
Insert Into A (Column1)
Values('Kapil')
Insert Into A (Column1)
Values('Dks')
Insert Into A (Column1)
Values('Sujeeth')
Insert Into A (Column1)
Values('Sks')
Insert Into A (Column1)
Values('Devid')
```

This is correct but i need any other option to insert?

Comment: (1) What database are you working with? please remove irrelevant tags. (2) The question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below approach

```
Insert Into A (Column1)
Values('Kapil'),('Dks'),('Sujeeth'),('Sks'),('Devid');
```

Hope this would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO A (Column1) VALUES ('Kapil'), ('Dks'), ('Sujeeth'), ('Sks'), ('Devid')
```